# mod_rewrite configuration does not work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page with urls like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?site=contact
http://example.com/index.php?site=about
```

So I try to create custom urls like

```
http://example.com/contact-the-person
http://example.com/cityname/about
```

to avoid duplicate content the first url need a permanent redirect into the new code.

this is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php?site=contact[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^/contact-the-person [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^contact-the-person/?$ index.php?site=contact [L,NC]
```

Update:

I changed my code into

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^cityname/about$ index.php?site=contact
```

and it works now. I can open the url with both links

```
http://example.com/index.php?site=contact
http://example.com/cityname/about
```

I just need a redirect from the php version to the clean url now, to avoid dublicate content

Comment: And? What happens? `does not work` does not tell us anything.

Comment: it happens nothing. if I call the url example.com/contact-the-person the browser outputs 'object no found' when I call the url example.com?site=contact the page works

Comment: 'object no found' (I guess you mean 'object *not* found'?) is not nothing! It tells us there is a 404, which means either no rule is matching, or a rule is matching and bouncing to the wrong target.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `RewriteBase`, if your base is `/` it is redundant and just complicates things.  I am not sure what your `RewriteCond` is doing, but it isn't necessary to do the 2 rewrites you describe in the question, so get rid of it too.

To make `/contact-the-person` work:

```
RewriteRule ^/contact-the-person index.php?site=contact [L,NC]
```

To make `/cityname/about` work:

```
RewriteRule ^/cityname/about index.php?site=about [L,NC]
```

So the complete file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/contact-the-person /index.php?site=contact [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/cityname/about /index.php?site=about [L,NC]
```

**UPDATE**

To also redirect your `index.php?site=contact` links to the new pretty format, you'll need to do an external redirect, so that the browser actually makes a new request, and the URL in the browser changes.  Do that by adding `R` to the flags.  `301` specifies the http response header, and will ensure your link rankings are preserved.  For the example you gave, add a new rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/index.php?site=contact /contact-the-person [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thank you, it works. do you have any idea how i can redirect the php url into the clean url? =)

Comment: it helped for the half. what I need is a redirect/forward. if someone calls the url index.php?site=contact, it should forward to /contact-the-person

Comment: I can call both URL's and nothings happen. here ich my code:

    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteRule ^contact-the-person$ index.php?site=contact [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^/index.php?site=contact /contact-the-person [L,R=301]

Comment: @AlperAydingül Your rules don't match what I wrote.